# On landscape the background blank

Tags: android

In landscape view, When the keyboard appears, the form in the background appears blank as the following picture:
[background blank](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wt9Uf.png).

When the keyboard slides down, the activity appears correctly. 
[The correct activity  view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ja1bm.png)

In the portrait view, it works fine.
 Can any one tell me how to fix it?

Comment: Hello, posting a small snippet of the code, so we are able to see what is going on might be able to help a lot, there could be a multitude of things wrong with your code.
include the XML and the activity it runs. (don't put to much code that is irrelevant)

Answer (score 0):

The keyboard opened in fullscreen mode, covering the entire Activity with it's own UI. A keyboard app can decide to do this if the screen is not large enough to show both itself and the Activity (e.g. landscape on a smartphone).

You can request the keyboard not to go fullscreen by adding the `noFullscreen` flag in xml:

```
<EditText
    ...
    android:imeOptions="flagNoFullscreen"
    />
```